# Equation with ceiling

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have to show that:
$$ \lceil{ \frac{\lceil{ \frac{n}{a} \rceil }}{b}} \rceil=\lceil {\frac{n}{ab} } \rceil$$
That`s what I tried:
If $n=ka, k \in \mathbb{Z}$: $ \lceil{ \frac{n}{a}} \rceil=\frac{n}{a}$,therefore the relation is satisfied.
But how can I show it,when $n \neq ka$ ?

Comment: $n,a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ or $n,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ or $n,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $n\geq 0$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Maybe this will help: $$\lceil x \rceil = x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(-x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}$$

Comment: Is this the only way to show it? :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way, I just said it might help...

Answer (score 2):

Write $\lceil \frac{n}{a}\rceil=\frac{n}{a}+\frac{\nu}{a}$, where $0\le \nu< a$.  Now $$\left\lceil \frac{\lceil \frac{n}{a}\rceil}{b} \right\rceil=\left\lceil \frac{ \frac{n}{a} + \frac{\nu}{a}}{b} \right\rceil=\left\lceil \frac{n}{ab}+\frac{\nu}{ab}\right\rceil ~~~(\star)$$

Now, there is some integer $t$ such that $(t-1)ab<n\le (t)ab$; specifically $t=\lceil \frac{n}{ab}\rceil$.  If we can show that $(\star)=t$ then we are done.

Comment: How can I show that $(\star)=t$ ?